# Unable to dynamically ng-include angular template in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs

I'm attempting to include templates dynamically using the following code.  All seems to work well until you enter the ng-repeat scope. I'm using angular1.2RC1.

http://plnkr.co/edit/S2e2w5PmMjrMwrgZKJW4?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.templateName = 'template1.html';

  $scope.templateConfig = [
    {
      templateName : 'template2.html'
    },
    {
      templateName : 'template3.html'
    }
  ];
});

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-include src="templateName"></div>

  <div ng-repeat="template in templateConfig">
    <div ng-include src="template.templateName"></div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I believe you either need to use ng-include="template.templateName" or ng-include src="{{template.templateName}}"

Comment: Tried both of those, to no avail.

Comment: Bug. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3627. So don't be always on bleeding edge. Use 1.0.7 instead.

Comment: @sza you're a genius! its working now: http://plnkr.co/edit/v79RugrGvbQyAUgYHA3l?p=preview

Comment: @Cherniv Oh thank you. I am not a genius, because I am doing this shit everyday...

Comment: @sza Using 1.0.7 isn't an option.  But... this has been fixed in the latest: http://plnkr.co/edit/MV5553HGpQehdMhzQ8KZ?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0-rc1" data-semver="1.2.0-rc1" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
```

New working plunker is on 
http://plnkr.co/edit/vDWk9h7R4VAGkkUTHRf0